# Como puedo colocar datos a una columna siendo esta NUMBER

Tags: sql

llevo mas de 2 horas intentando resolver este problema, este aparece cuando intento colocar datos en una tabla PRECIOS que es de tipo NUMBER

Codigo Error: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SQL_SGQANLJTIGKSTUOBCPETPMEBN"."EVENT"."FECHA")

```
ALTER TABLE EVENT
ADD PRECIO NUMBER

INSERT INTO EVENT (COD_EVENTO, PRECIO) 
VALUES ('10','650000')
```

Comment: El error dice que se no se puede ingresar un valor `null` en el campo fecha. Pásale un valor para la fecha.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! ademas, para agregar numeros no necesitas pasar los datos entre comillas simples... esas son cadenas...